# ReactJS: dynamically display a subset of elements

Tags: javascript, reactjs

So I’m running into a situation where I have a component using state ‘type’ to display a subset of elements. But sometimes, this component can be rendered when coming from a different page after clicking a “back” button, so I also this a props ‘type’, and want to display a subset of elements based on this.props.type. So how could I use this.state.type as an initial state to display the list, then later use this.props.type to display a different list? Or am I using the wrong approach entirely? I'm still pretty new to React.

The component is like this:

```
class campaignList extends Component {

  constructor(props) {
     super(props);
     this.state = {};
     this.state = {type:ChallengeConstants.TYPE_QUESTS_EXPERIMENT};
  }

  render() {

     return (
        <div>
           <div className="container">
              <div className="row">
                 <div className="col">
                    <div className="btn-group">
                       <button className="btn btn-info btn-sm" onClick={()=>this.setState({type:ChallengeConstants.TYPE_QUESTS_EXPERIMENT})} >Quests</button>
                       <button className="btn btn-info btn-sm" onClick={()=>this.setState({type:ChallengeConstants.TYPE_COLLECTIONS_EXPERIMENT})} >Collections</button>
                       <button className="btn btn-info btn-sm" onClick={()=>this.setState({type:ChallengeConstants.TYPE_SPECIAL_QUESTS_EXPERIMENT})} >Special Quests</button>
                       <button className="btn btn-info btn-sm" onClick={()=>this.setState({type:"others"})} >Other Campaigns</button>
                    </div>
                 </div>
              </div>
           </div>
           <table className="table table-striped">
              <thead>
                 <tr>

                 </tr>
              </thead>
              <tbody>
                 {this.props.campaigns.filter(this.separateCampaignsByExperimentType.bind(this)).map(this.renderCampaignRow.bind(this))}
              </tbody>
           </table>
        </div>
     );
  }

  // separate the campaigns by type
  separateCampaignsByExperimentType(campaign) {
     if (campaign.experiment === this.state.type) {
        return true;
     }
  }
};
```

Comment: `this.state = {type: props.type || ChallengeConstants.TYPE_QUESTS_EXPERIMENT};`?

Comment: ha, I didn't know I could do that! Thank you so much!

Answer (score 0):

You can just do:

```
this.state = {type: props.type || ChallengeConstants.TYPE_QUESTS_EXPERIMENT};
```